# Color shift uploading to Youtube

Tags: color, animation, video

I have an animation i After Effects (1920x1080, 25fps, Color working space sRGB 1966) with Illustrator doc in sRGB. The colors are correct when playing in project and also when exported and playing in Quicktime & VLC.

But when uploading to Youtube and on other webpages the colors shift, especially one color (#00acc1) turquoise gets much more green. Like this [image: Turquoise vs Aqua]

Left color - the right one and Right color - the color I get from Youtube.

This is in Firefox. But when I play the same video in Chrome & Safari the colors are all correct in the video - except the startpicture (miniature from Youtube) gets the wrong color. Weird!

I have tried different codec-options in AE and Adobe Media Encoder (H.264, Youtube preset, Animation etc). I tried YUV (thought that less compression would make it better, since Youtube is already compressing it) and it got better I thought at first, but then I saw it just go more blue and in Chrome it got TOO much blue - so the color shift is still there. I also tried putting the masterclip in AE and setting a Utility profile converter to sRGB - but same shift there when uploading to web.

I have been trying to solve this for hours. I understand that colors can shift inbetween browsers and different screens, but this seems too much. Is this specific color extremely non-web-friendly? Or is there anything I can do about this, is it something I'm doing wrong or has anyone experienced something similar?

Thanks for reply!

Comment: Take a look at http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/4912/possible-to-use-srgb-as-mp4-colorspace/10674#10674

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Possible to use sRGB as mp4 colorspace?](http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/4912/possible-to-use-srgb-as-mp4-colorspace)